# locking does not work properly in dining philosophers

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety

I am implementing dining philosopher solution but mostly my philosopher thinking.
rarely eating food, I wonder my  implementation is true or not true
my purpose if left fork is available locked after if right fork is available lock then eat can I achieve ?

I am expecting

```
thinking
thinking
thinking
thinking
thinking
eating number 2
thinking
eating number 1
thinking
eating number 5
```

but always thinking state comes, how do I figure out this problem

```
class Fork:
    def __init__(self, index: int):
        self.index: int = index
        self.lock: threading.Lock = threading.Lock()
        self.picked_up: bool = False
        self.owner: int = -1

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __call__(self, owner: int):
        if self.lock.acquire():
            self.owner = owner
            self.picked_up = True
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.lock.release()
        self.picked_up = False
        self.owner = -1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"F{self.index:2d} ({self.owner:2d})"


class Philosopher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, index: int, left_fork: Fork, right_fork: Fork,eat_max:int):
        super().__init__()
        self.index: int = index
        self.left_fork: Fork = left_fork
        self.right_fork: Fork = right_fork
        self.spaghetti: int = 0
        self.eat_max:int= eat_max 

    def run(self):
        while self.spaghetti < self.eat_max:
            self.think()
            self.eat()

    def think(self):
        time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
        print(f"philosopher {self.index} thinking")
        

    def eat(self):
        if not self.left_fork.picked_up:
            with self.left_fork(self.index):
                time.sleep(random.uniform(1, 2))
                if not self.right_fork.picked_up:
                    with self.right_fork(self.index):
                        self.spaghetti += 1
                        time.sleep(random.uniform(2, 2.5))
                        print(f"philosopher {self.index} eating")
                       


def main() -> None:
    n: int = 5
    m: int = 2
    forks: list[Fork] = [Fork(i) for i in range(n)]
    philosophers: list[Philosopher] = [
        Philosopher(i, forks[i], forks[(i + 1) % n], m) for i in range(n)
    ]
    for philosopher in philosophers:
        philosopher.start()
    
    for philosopher in philosophers:
        philosopher.join()

    for philosopher in philosophers:
        print(
            f"philosopher {philosopher.index} has eaten {philosopher.spaghetti} pieces"
        )
```

Comment: I have not really looked at the come but why do you feel you can or should be able to predict the output of a multiprosessing task that involves random sleeps?

Comment: it looks eat function does not work rarely working @JonSG I am missing a point but I could not saw.

Comment: Notice that the `Fork.__exit__()` has a bug with respect to the handling of the lock: The lock is unlocked first, then the state of `picked_up` and `owner` is modified; therefor that state-changed is unprotected by the lock. The `__call__`-implementation (besides the weird structure of this code) suggests that these two variables should be protected by the lock. As it is currently written, its possible for thread A to acquire the lock, modify the values, release the lock, thread B now acquiring the lock and observing the values, and thread A to only now modify them in `__exit__`.

Comment: As a side-note, notice that `threading.Lock.acquire()` with no parameters can [only ever return `True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire), so the `if` is actually screen-noise.

Comment: @user2722968 enter and exit is enough ıdk call is required?

Comment: @01d, I can't understand what you are saying here. To clarify: My point is that `self.lock.release()` needs to be at the **end** of `__exit__()`, not the beginning. I don't know if this is your actual problem, but this _is_ a bug.